# How do I set Primary Key | SAS Studio

Tags: sas

I'm trying to set Primary Key on SAS and I keep getting the error mentioned below.
Any help would be great!

The first snippet is code and the next is the error.

```
/*Primary Key*/ /*Defines the unique key*/

Proc datasets lib=work;
modify WORK.FinAdvMaster;
ic create primary key(FinAdvID);
PROC PRINT DATA=WORK.FinAdvMaster; RUN;**strong text**
```

The error I get -

```
 96         /*Primary Key*/ /*Defines the unique key*/
 97         
 98         Proc datasets lib=work;
 99         modify WORK.FinAdvMaster;
                   _________________
                   22
                   201
 ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name.
 ERROR 201-322: The option is not recognized and will be ignored.
 100        ic create primary key(FinAdvID);
 NOTE: Enter RUN; to continue or QUIT; to end the procedure.
```

Comment: I've use SAS a long time ago, but AFAIK SAS did not have a concept of primary key... since it is more as a analytics program instead of a RDBMS...

Comment: but maybe you can just create a unique index which function similar to a PK.

Comment: let me try that.

Comment: You can create a primary key with SAS. It mainly is just a shortcut for adding the `not null` and `unique` ICs.

Comment: Just delete the `work.` in modify statement because it has been declared in `lib=` option.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `work.` from your modify statement. The `lib=` option specifies the library. It's a quirk of `proc datasets`.

```
proc datasets lib=work;
    modify FinAdvMaster;
        ic create primary key (FinAdvID);
quit;
```

Note that this key will be destroyed if you recreate the dataset.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL to add a column constraint specifying `PRIMARY KEY`

Example:

```
proc sql; 

  create table work.class as select * from sashelp.class;

  alter table work.class add constraint pk_name primary key(name);
```

In your case

```
alter table FinAdvMaster
add constraint 
  pk_FinAdvID primary key(FinAdvID)
;
```

`pk_<column-name>` is a common convention for naming primary keys.